# Structuring MongoDB data and mongoose queries

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm trying to figure out how to strcuture my models and queries for my app. I'm using express, mongoose, and mongodb.

Bascially, my app is meant to be for events (parties, tournaments, get-togethers, etc.). I have a model for users and events. I'm trying to make it so that a user can be invited to an event. The 'invite' would be have a status: 'invited', 'accepted', 'declined'. My original idea was to have this:

```
    let eventSchema = new Schema({
    Date:{
        type: Date,
        required: true
    },
    Title:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    Description:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    Owner:{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
        required: true
    },
    Invites: {
        invited : [
            {
                type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                ref: 'User'
            }
        ],
        accepted: [
            {
                type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                ref: 'User'
            }

        ],
        declined: [
            {
                type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                ref: 'User'
            }
        ]

    }
});
```

This is the user schema:

```
let userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    firstName:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    lastName:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    email:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    type:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    events:{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'events',
    }
});
```

This is the document in my database (in mlab):

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5b84adca83599470e9d95d90"
    },
    "Invites": {
        "invited": [
            {
                "$oid": "5b817c2ae7179a43f9ac854e"
            },
            {
                "$oid": "5b817c8ae7179a43f9ac8577"
            }
        ],
        "accepted": [],
        "declined": []
    },
    "Title": "Testtttt",
    "Date": {
        "$date": "2018-08-29T04:00:00.000Z"
    },
    "Description": "testttttt",
    "Owner": {
        "$oid": "5b817c2ae7179a43f9ac854e"
    },
    "__v": 0
}
```

I'm trying to make it so that I can display the event and all of it's details. I'm running in to problems with JS's asynchronicity I believe.

Here's what I have for the function to 'view' an event's details:

```
const displayEventDetails = (req, res, next) => {
    let id = req.params.id;

    Event.findById(id)
        .populate('Owner')
        .exec((err, event) => {
            var tmpEvent = event.toObject();
            var tmpInvitees = [];
            var invitees = tmpEvent.Invites.invited;
            console.trace(invitees);
            invitees.forEach(invitee => {
                User.findById(invitee, (err, invitee) => {
                    tmpInvitees.push(invitee);
                });
            });
            if (err)
                console.log("Error Selecting : %s ", err);
            if (!event)
                return res.render('404');
            // console.trace(event);
            res.render('event_details',
                {
                    event,
                    invitees: tmpInvitees
                }
            );

        });
};
```

**Anyone have any ideas on how I can get it so that the above function will return both the event and the invitees? I believe that it's rendering before the .forEach method can finish and so invitees is emtpy...**

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: full code can be found here: https://github.com/thanover/event_manager

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out. Using this worked:

```
const displayEventDetails = (req, res, next) => {
    let id = req.params.id;

    Event.findById(id)
        .populate('Owner')
        .populate('Invites.invited')
        .populate('Invites.accepted')
        .populate('Invites.declined')
        .exec((err, event) => {
            if (err)
                console.log("Error Selecting : %s ", err);
            if (!event)
                return res.render('404');
            var invited = event.Invites.invited;
            var accepted = event.Invites.accepted;
            var declined = event.Invites.declined;
            res.render('event_details', {
                event,
                invited,
                accepted,
                declined
            });
        });
};
```